# Is it possible to continuously query newly added data from Microsoft SQL Server using node-mssql?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, socket.io, node-mssql

Here is the case:

There is real-time data acquisition software continuously pushing new data to my SQL Server (about 8 rows per 1 sec). What I want to do is that using node-mssql and socket.io to get the newly added data, push them to the client sides and show the real-time data on chart(by HighCharts).

Is it possible? And what's the best practice to do it?